# Use JQ to form new arrays from items in arrays by index

Tags: arrays, csv, jq

I have some JSON data which is pretty typical CSV-style data, however it's represented in JSON. I am struggling to figure out the correct `jq` expression to convert the following JSON back to some JSON which can generate the appropriate CSV with `@csv`.

There's a fixed number of 'columns', i.e. the `"AAA"` values, but the number of values in each 'column' is dynamic yet fixed across columns. That is, the length of the arrays `"AAA"`, `"BBB"`, `"CCC"`, etc are all the same, but the length is dynamic and can change between data sets.

Input (note invalid numbers present, to illustrate example):

```json
{
  "AAA": [
    111.1,
    111.2,
    111.3,
    111..,
    111.n
  ],
  "BBB": [
    222.1,
    222.2,
    222.3,
    222..,
    222.n
  ],
  "CCC": [
    333.1,
    333.2,
    333.3,
    333..,
    333.n
  ],
  "DDD": [
    444.1,
    444.2,
    444.3,
    444..,
    444.n
  ],
  "EEE": [
    555.1,
    555.2,
    555.3,
    555..,
    555.n
  ]
}
```

Desired output (note invalid numbers present, to illustrate example):

```json
{
  [        
    "AAA", 
    "BBB", 
    "CCC", 
    "DDD", 
    "EEE"  
  ],
  [
    111.1,
    222.1,
    333.1,
    444.1,
    555.1
  ],
  [
    111.2,
    222.2,
    333.2,
    444.2,
    555.2
  ],
  [
    111.3,
    222.3,
    333.3,
    444.3,
    555.3
  ],
  [
    111..,
    222..,
    333..,
    444..,
    555..
  ],
  [
    111.n,
    222.n,
    333.n,
    444.n,
    555.n
  ]
}
```

Here is the desired CSV, for illustration purposes (as converting with `@csv` is pretty straightforward):

```
AAA,BBB,CCC,DDD,EEE
111.1,222.1,333.1,444.1,555.1
111.2,222.2,333.2,444.2,555.2
111.3,222.3,333.3,444.3,555.3
111..,222..,333..,444..,555..
111.n,222.n,333.n,444.n,555.n
```

If the required expression is far easier without the first array in the result object containing the `"AAA"` 'header' values then I can easily live without them.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `transpose` function in `jq` to do the transposing of arrays, formed from keys/values.

```
jq '[ to_entries[] | [.key, .value[]] ] | transpose'
```

The bulk of the magic is performed by the transpose built-in, but before that you just need to collect the values into an array of arrays. The CSV result can be generated with the `@csv` function.

```
jq --raw-output '[ to_entries[] | [.key, .value[]] ] | transpose[] | @csv'
```

You could also use `map()` and be avoid the redundant `[..]`

```
jq 'to_entries | map([.key, .value[]]) | transpose'
jq --raw-output 'to_entries | map([.key, .value[]]) | transpose[] | @csv'
```

Comment: These work perfectly - thanks a lot @Inian! Looks like I was probably only halfway there in my use of `to_entries` and `transpose`, so I would've been struggling for quite some time to get the outcome I needed. Thanks again.